# resource with http or not? change site speed?

Tags: html, performance

Use this:

```
<link href="http://www.alessandrapinto.it/css/real-style.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

or this:

```
<link href="css/real-style.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Can change speed of my website?

All 2 example is in same domain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at your server logs. Server receives same path in the end, so it is purely client-side manipulations. So answer is no.